# Rectangle in AI compressed file

Tags: pdf, adobe-illustrator, compression

I am parsing an ai file which contains a rectangle which is described into "49 0 obj" into a "Layer".

When I save this file as compressed, the 49th object is missing. Although I am decompressing each portion of the file that is compressed (e.g. /Filter/FlateDecode) I cannot find the information that describes the rectangle.

Any ideas?

Thank you,
Michael.

Comment: The file, the file, my kingdom for the file. Seriously, you have to provide a sample file for these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you posted the file.
When I see `49 0 obj`, I think PDF, not Illustrator, perhaps it's PDF encoded Illustrator?

Let's assume that it is. If you can't find that object, likely what you're looking at is one or more embedded object stream (section 7.5.7 in the PDF spec).

If you see something like this:

```
<< /Type ObjStm /N 13 /First 13 >> stream
```

Then that's exactly what you have.

When you crack open the stream, it starts with a set of integer pairs that are object number and offsets to the objects within the stream.

Comment: And how can I crack open the stream? 1. Yes you are right it is a pdf encoded illustrator file. 2. I have an object like this:

`<</Length 654352/N 4>>stream
üADBE  prtrCMYKLab .....`

I have read what you have mentioned but I did not manage to find how can I can I crack this stream.

(Thank you for your response and I am sorry for the delay)

Comment: plinth did not mean just *any* random stream (which is what you show), but more particular an *object stream*: "An object stream, is a stream object in which a sequence of indirect objects may be stored, as an alternative to their being stored at the outermost file level." (from PDF 32000-1:2008). ((And it might help if you posted the file.))